# Solder mask free regions on PCB

Tags: soldering, solder-mask

I have noticed many PCBs with solder mask free regions/areas on the edges. I am attaching an image with this. What is the purpose of such areas ? What I can think of is heat transfer to the ambient region around the PCB. In that case what is the need to remove Solder mask ? Does Solder mask trap the heat from escaping into the surrounding ?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please mark the refereed area in your image?

Comment: In many cases, such traces are designed to conduct big current. In many cases this kind of traces are also soldered, to increase conductivity.

Comment: In the lower image, the thick lines could be mounting areas for shielding boxes. That would explain the huge amount of stitching vias.

Comment: Hello Botnic. I have added another image showing the said regions. I understand the shielding tracks. What about the large mass to bottom left(extreme). I reckon that would be used for tinning with solder.

Comment: It doesn't look like heat spreaders to me. Where should the heat come from? But to tell the function, I would need to know more about the PCB.
I can imagine, that the lower triangle area is used to connect the casing to the PCB (but just guessing)

Comment: Taking a guess on the functionality based on the top picture - looks like the PCB involves RF and/or very high speed circuitry. The exposed tracks would then be for soldering on shielding cans, or possibly mounting shielding directly onto it. I agree with Botnic that the triangular spot looks pretty ideal for soldering a ground cable which can then be mounted to the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have seen mentioned in the comments, this could be used to apply solder to conduct higher currents.

However, I don't believe that is the intended purpose in the photos provided.  Notice how the exposed traces surround specific sections of the board completely, and don't appear to be connected to anything except likely to ground.  There are also a large number of stitching vias. This would be connected to a metal can or some other shielding.

Comment: Yes, and the larger holes along those traces are for the tabs at the bottom of the can/fence.